# auto function return type + rvalue overload = ambigious call?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, rvalue-reference, type-deduction

I'm looking for a reason this won't compile (gcc, c++14)

```
#include <iostream>

class Widget
{
  private:
    int i = 0;
  public:
    auto get() & { return i;}
    auto get() && { return i+1;}
};

int main()
{
  Widget w;
  auto val = w.get();
  std::cout<<val;
}
```

The error is

```
23:31: error: call of overloaded 'get()' is ambiguous
23:31: note: candidates are:
10:10: note: auto Widget::get()
11:10: note: auto Widget::get()
```

It works if I use explicit return type for get() functions

```
int get() & { return i;}
int get() && { return i+1;}
```

Comment: Compiles for me with gcc 8.3. I didn't try other versions. [Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/ur7Gnt)

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried it with cpp shell only and it failed. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your version of GCC? (You can get it by typing `g++ -v` in your terminal)

Comment: I used http://www.cppshell.com to test this code and nothing else to compare results, my bad. cppshell uses GCC 4.9.2, which according to https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html should support function return type deduction.